# How to parse UTF-16 encoded XML string with Poco library?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, utf-16, poco-libraries

I want to parse a UTF-16 encoded XML string stored in an `std::u16string` object using `Poco::DOMParser`. However, its `parseString()` function only takes `std::string` parameter and it does not have any overload taking `std::u16string`.

What's the recommended approach to parse UTF-16 XML string in Poco? I can think of using `parseMemory()` by converting my UTF-16 string to a byte array. Is this ok or is there something better?

Comment: If Poco doesn't support UTF-8 encoding, give up Poco. But if it does, convert to UTF-8.

Comment: Looking at the `API` you could try calling `setEncoding` to `UTF-16le` (with the correct endianness) and then use `parseMemory` passing `(char const*) u16str.c_str()` as its parameter.

Comment: @Galik, `parseMemory` also takes a size parameter. It needs to be given the size in bytes of the UTF-16 XML from u16string object. It works but I want to know if any string parsing is possible.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I'm getting the UTF-16 XML from a legacy application and it needs to be parsed frequently. Converting to UTF-8 every time may not be a good option.

Comment: @KapilDhaimade: The first rule of optimization: **measure**. Most likely as UTF-8 the data is half the size. That can improve parsing speed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Yes, I know. I'll do a profiling. Maybe we can avoid UTF-16. Thanks!